# Is there a way to have Eclipse automatically make all my variables final?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I try to avoid having non-final variables when possible, and it would save some typing if Eclipse would automate this for me (also so I don't forget to do it). What I'd like is for it to detect when I add a new variable assignment/declaration statement, and as soon as I finish it, insert the `final` modifier.

Is there a configuration option or lightweight plugin that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can add it as a '**Save Action**' so that whenever you save a file, Eclipse will add `final` to your variables. This is how:

- Go to **Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions**
- Tick **Additional Actions** and press **Configure**
- In the **Code Style** tab there is a section on **Variable declarations** and you can tick **Use modifier
  'final' where possible**. You can choose between private fields, parameters and local variables.

Or you can do the same thing manually (every once in while or for existing code base) via **Clean up**

Comment: The day they realize that catch-declarations and for-vars are **not** the same as local var declarations, I'll enable this option myself :) For now, I still have to do it by hand.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik For foreach vars (e.g., `for ( final Object x : … ) { … }`) there's not much problem, but iteration variables `for ( int i = 0 ; … ; i++ ) { … }`, there'd be a problem.  Do you often have occasion to assign to catch declarations?  I don't see much problem with `try { } catch ( final Exception e ) { … }`…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Seems you're missing my point... the problem is in having all those `final` keywords adding noise to your code. What I would prefer is final being the *default* and a special keyword needing to be applied to get a mutable variable.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I definitely agree on that point. It's nice that Java has a concept now of "effectively final" (where variables references in lambda expressions must be final or effectively final), but I too wish that final were the default, and mutability was enabled with a particular keyword. Your comment led me to think that you weren't concerned about noise so much as the (im)mutability of catch variables and for variables.  Obviously iteration variables need to be mutable, but catch variables don't really need to be.  But that's a different concern from the noise.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the right click --> source --> clean-up.
You should first define in the Code Formatter part of the preference what you really want to be cleaned.

Comment: It does not add it "as soon as you finish it" but you can just don't care with final modifiers while typing and adding them at the end with the clean-up.

Answer (score 2):

`Checkstyle` Plugin can do this for you. You have to setup your checkstyle configuration first then enable checkstyle in your project, and let it change your code upon saving a java file.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most robust solution but for primitives and/or types you use a lot you could define macros

```
int --> final int
byte[] --> final byte[]
List --> final List
```

I really like the formatter idea too, but then you have to accept every other piece of formatting it has, which can be cumbersome.